# Is there an API to the AppHarbor management domain?

Tags: appharbor

For example, if my app needed to add a new domain name to my application via an API call how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppHarbor has an API that lets you accomplish most management functions including creating hostnames. Documentation is here:

- [Overview](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/api-overview)
- [Create hostname](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/hostnames-api#create)